# Two mutually singular and absolutely continuous measures means one measure is identically zero

Tags: measure-theory

The claim is that if $\nu$ is a signed measure on (X,M) and $\mu$ is a positive measure on M, $\nu\perp\mu$, and $\nu<<\mu$, then $\nu=0$.

I can see that $\nu=0$ if $\mu(E)=0$ by absolute continuity. I am having trouble seeing why $\nu(E)=0$ when $\mu(E)>0$. For example, I have drawn two disjoint circles representing A and B, and another circle representing E intersecting both A and B. In this case, $\mu(B\cap E)>0$ and $\nu(A\cap E)>0$. Could someone explain to me why this drawing/idea is not a counterexample to the claim? It

(Definitions: $\nu\perp\mu$ means the two measures are mutually singular, i.e. there exist disjoint sets A and B in M such that $\nu(E)=\nu(A\cap E)$ and $\mu(E)=\mu(B\cap E)$ for all $E\in M$; $\nu<<\mu$ means $\nu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\mu$, i.e. $\nu(E)=0$ whenever $E\in M$ and $\mu(E)=0$.)

Comment: Suppose $\nu$ is a signed measure on (X,M) and $\mu$ is a positive measure on M, $\nu\perp\mu$, and $\nu\ll\mu$. 

Since $\nu\perp\mu$, there exist disjoint sets A and B in M such that $\nu(E)=\nu(A\cap E)$ and $\mu(E)=\mu(B\cap E)$ for all $E\in M$. But then, for all $E\in M$ we have  $$\mu(A\cap E)=\mu(B\cap A\cap E)=\mu(\emptyset)=0$$
Since $\nu\ll\mu$, we have that $\nu(E)=\nu(A\cap E)=0$. So, for all $E\in M$, $\nu(E)=0$.

Comment: Great, thanks Ramiro!

Comment: Since both of you, @Ramiro and manofbear are still active on the Math.SE, care to write the comment as an answer and accept it?